# how to use str.replace() as the function in map()

Tags: python

I have a list of rows returned from an excel sheet. I want to use the replace function on each item in row to replace `'` with `\'`

however, this does not work:

```
row = map(replace('\'', "\\'"), row)
```

this just gives an error about replace taking at most 3 arguments but only having 2.

is there a way to use replace with map in python?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
map( lambda s: s.replace(...), row )
```

or use a list comprehension

```
[s.replace(...) for s in row]
```

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic Python here is probably to use a list comprehension:

```
row = [ x.replace('\'', "\\'") for x in row ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The first arg to replace is a function; what you have is an attempt at a function call.

Forget map. Use

```
row = [x.replace(something, other) for x in row]
```

Answer (score 2):

In theory the optimised way is

```
map(operator.methodcaller("replace", '\'', '\\\''), ...)
```

In practice, a list comprehension is probably neater.

---

If you are trying to escape a string, there may be a better way (for instance, [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape)).

Answer (score 1):

```
row = map(lambda x: x.replace('\'', "\\'"), row)
```

Alternatively you could use `re`'s replace function.